# Channels works in development but not in production when passing user info

Tags: nginx, django-channels

I am using channels 2.x (along with nginx, daphne, redis and gunicorn) The odd is I can access the the user with the development server on my local machine using javascript but in my production environment (everything else works, but the user is undefined. Note: the user is logged in.

Does anyone have any idea why that might be?

class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):

## followed tutorial

```
def chat_message(self, event):
    message = event['message']

    # Send message to WebSocket
    self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
        'user': self.scope["user"].first_name, # <<< my line
        'message': message
    }))
```

console.log produces: channels data["user"]: undefined

Comment: Are they running on the same domain thee production environment as in the development environment?

Comment: The development environment is local, so no.

Comment: I mean the frontend and the server in production

Comment: yes they are the same